# Why is this iptables blocking the ssh to my virtual machine?

Tags: ssh, iptables, kali-linux

I have a virtual machine with kali running a ssh server, i want to block all traffic by ssh to this machine except from my own pc and to do it i have this iptables rules.

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  DESKTOP-JMUOD0E.home  anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 419 packets, 33340 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  *      *       192.168.1.71         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
2        0     0 DROP       6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 332 packets, 42224 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:de:55:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.24/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 86249sec preferred_lft 86249sec
    inet6 fe80::5a15:2c68:b1af:e663/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

what i am doing wrong? because my pc cant enter if the last rule is active but the rule has the ip of my pc...

i think is because of the adapter of my virtual machine and the nat, what you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer, it was the NAT of the virtual machine as I thought.

Probably the translation of the ip of my pc to the vm network was giving troubles to the iptables, if I put the bridge mode works just fine.

[image: My vm adapter]